# Continuation to Divisional

Tags: application

An application is being filed as a continuation application. After filing that can it be changed to a Divisional applicaiton at a later stage?

Answer (score 1):

Continuation and divisional applications originate under different conditions. Divisional application is typically carved out from the original application when the examiner issues a restriction requirement if the original application is shown to have more than one distinct inventions. Continuation application is filed when you would like to file additional claims for the invention disclosed in the parent - this you can initiate.

So you can have a divisional application carved out from that application if the examiner issues a restriction requirement and based on that requirement but you cannot voluntarily file or convert the continuation to divisional.